# Windows 7 logon screensaver in Delphi

Tags: delphi, windows-7, screensaver, authentication

I'm having problems while using Delphi application as Windows 7 logon screensaver (for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows). Even blank application (New Project without any extra code) throws an error.

Delphi 7 application throws "The memory could not be read" error and Delphi 2010 application throws "The exception unknown software exception occurred in the application" and then "Runtime error 217". This error happens before any form initialization and before any initialization of exception handlers.

Setting notepad.exe as logon screensaver works fine.

Any ideas what goes on here?

Comment: (And I just had to try NOTEPAD.EXE as logon screensaver! What a mess! I also just had to try File/Open to see what I could access and not!)

Comment: Andreas: LOL ;) now I wan to set a spectrum 3 loader screen as logon screensaver. so we need to find out how!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand From File/Open, you can hold Shift down and right click a folder to open a command prompt. I was able to run regedit, but wasn't able to change anything. It seems security restriction does limit some of what you can do. However, what's scarier is doing the same not for .DEFAULT, but your own user account. The "screensaver" (i.e. Notepad) runs in the context of **your own account**. And you still have full access. In other words even if I lock my desktop without clicking Switch User to go to the main Logon screen - I'm not locked out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in my comment, it's not "invisible code", just code in the initialization section of some unit that's causing the problem. I've managed to track down the culprit (well at least one of them - there may be others).

When you use the `Forms` unit, it has a dependency on the `Classes` unit.

The initialization section calls `InitThreadSynchronization`, which amongst other things calls the following:

```
SyncEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, '');
if SyncEvent = 0 then
  RaiseLastOSError;
```

It seems the API call `CreateEvent` fails when called from within the login screen. Unfortunately I'm unsure whether the login screen: (a) forbids `CreateEvent` altogether (b) requires `CreateEventEx` instead or (c) would work with an appropriate `lpEventAttributes` argument. I've posted a more specific question to hopefully find out: [CreateEvent from Windows-7 Logon Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24726463/224704)

You can verify the problem with the following console app:

```
program TestLoginScreensaver;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

var
  SyncEvent: THandle;

begin
  try
    SyncEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, '');
    if SyncEvent = 0 then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    CloseHandle(SyncEvent); //So handle is closed if it was created (e.g. while logged in)
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

The purpose of `SyncEvent` is to enable `TThread` instances to synchronise back to the main thread. So if you write a single threaded app, or create your threads using something other than `TThread`, you don't actually need/use `SyncEvent` at all.

> **SIDE-RANT**: This is a prime example of the problem with using the **initialization** section. Merely including a unit has the potential to introduce unnecessary side-effects. They're *Mostly Harmless*, but not in this case. Now you may argue that `Classes.pas` is bloated, and I won't argue. But the point is that if Classes initialization were called **explicitly** from the DPR, this problem would have been easier to identify and find a workaround for.

---

#### EDIT: New Solution

As Remy Lebeau noted in the other question I posted.
The line:

```
    SyncEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, '');
```

Must be changed to:

```
    SyncEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
```

Since this solution involves recompiling VCL units, you may want to go through a few of the [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+recompile+vcl+units) on this subject

With this as the only change (compiled in D2009) I was able to successfully show a blank form at the Logon screen. However, bear in mind that some things you may normally expect to be able to do will be off limits due to the security restrictions at the Logon screen.

Comment: This sounds terribly complicated so I can't just go and test the solution right now but I have no reason to doubt this works so I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: You don't need to recompile the RTL/VCL. Since the offending code is only in the `implementation` section and not the `interface` section, you can make a copy of `Classes.pas` and modify it accordingly, then add the modified file directly to your project. The modified code will override the native code imported from the RTL. Just make sure that Runtime Packages are disabled, or this will not work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Correct; as you say. @Kaitnieks, to clarify... The solution is only a small change to `Classes.pas`. When I said "involves recompiling VCL units": I'm not saying you have to recompile the "whole of RTL/VCL". `Classes.pas` is a RTL/VCL unit, so you have to recompile at least that one. I found I also had to recompile `Controls.pas`. I was a little surprised because my change was implementation only; and why not other units like Forms.pas? But I didn't bother to investigate further. The link to questions on recompiling VCL units should help if you get stuck.

Comment: The `Classes.pas` bug has now been reported to QC: [#126105 Bad CreateEvent() lpName parameter value being used in System.Classes.InitThreadSynchronization()](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=126105)

Answer (score 1):

After a little playing around. This has to be connected to Delphi's hidden main (real main) window you will need to look seriously at Application.initialise or Application.HookMainWindow().

Because amazingly this code does not cause a problem:

```
program w7logonsaver;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 20 do
    writeln;
  write('K ');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Just hit enter to quit.

Comment: It happens before Application.Initialize. In some invisible code I suppose.

Comment: @Kaitnieks Not "invisible", just code in the initialisation section of some unit. You might be able to narrow down which VCL unit by including/excluding certain units in your program.