# CreateEvent from Windows-7 Logon Screen

Tags: security, delphi, winapi, windows-7, winlogon

I'm asking this question because it turns out that there's some difficulty in writing a screensaver app in Delphi that's capable of running from the Logon screen.

See question: [Windows 7 logon screensaver in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5567775/224704)

I've narrowed down the problem (or at least one problem) to a particular Win API call `CreateEvent`.

```
SyncEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, '');
if SyncEvent = 0 then
  RaiseLastOSError;
```

This code only fails if called from the Logon screen. And GetLastError returns that access is denied. So clearly the security restrictions on the Logon screen prevent `CreateEvent(nil, True, False, '');` from creating the event as desired.

(I don't really see how an Event could be an exploitable security risk.)

So, the question is: Is it possible to create an Event from the Logon screen? Presumably via either:

- Using an appropriate `lpEventAttributes`
- Or calling CreatingEventEx instead.

*Although the problem was experienced in Delphi, this is more about the Win API. So feel free to answer in your language of choice*.

Comment: Craig, I'm absolutely no expert at this and maybe I dreamt it, but I'm sure there was a question about this in the Borland groups back in the Win2k or even NT era and the answer at the time was that you had to supply a replacement for Gina.Dll if you wanted to do anything inside the Windows station of the logon screen.  Acc to this q, it's different post XP but I imagine you knew that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917790/a-gina-replacement-in-a-net-language

Comment: @MartynA I must confess much of this is new to me. I just did some investigation because the question about Logon screensavers piqued my interest. However, I have my doubts about GINA being relevant because [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9506690/224704) suggests that GINA has been replaced as of Windows Vista. Also, I don't know what the asker of the Logon screensaver question actually intended doing. Perhaps he wanted to write a simple slideshow screensaver. It turns out that of the standard Win-7 screensavers, only the blank screen works due to Direct3D restrictions.

Comment: Try setting the last parameter of `CreateEvent()` to `nil` instead of `''`.  There is a difference between a nil pointer and a pointer to a zero-length string. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396.aspx) does not say anything about a zero-length string being treated any differently than any other named string. If you want an unnamed event, use `nil`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Excellent catch! Please go ahead and post as an answer.

Comment: @Anonymous downvoter: Mind sharing what's wrong with the question so I can do better next time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the last parameter of `CreateEvent()`
to `nil` instead of `''` . There is a difference between
a nil pointer and a pointer to a zero-length string. The
[documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396.aspx) does not say anything about a zero-
length string being treated any differently than any
 other named string. So maybe there is another zero-length-named event that exists somewhere else on your machine that your app does not have access to, thus the Access Denied error when `CreateEvent()` tries to access the existing event and fails. If you want to create an unnamed event,
 use `nil` instead.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now that I'm more consciously aware that `PChar` is a little richer than `string` in its ability to differentiate `nil` and `''`, it's led me to discover more little mistakes in Delphi. E.g. `TSimpleEvent` in SyncObjs wraps `CreateEvent` with the constructor taking a string for the name. So it's impossible to create an unnamed event. Even worse it doesn't check the result of the API call, so if you use `TSimpleEvent` from a Logon screensaver, you'll quietly get a useless `TSimpleEvent` instance.

Comment: The `T(Simple)Event` bug has already been reported to QC, and still exists in XE6: [#100175 SyncObjs.TEvent invalid construction](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=100175)